# Perlbrew | установка cpanm для произвольной версии perl

Tags: linux, perl

В системе кроме стандартного perl5.8.8 стоит, установленный с помощью perlbrew, perl5.10.1

При попытке установить локальный cpanm для него, ругается..

```
[shev_ay@pandora 20120203]$ perl -v
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-linux

[shev_ay@pandora 20120203]$ curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus                                                                                     
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  319k  100  319k    0     0  97867      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  276k
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-    multi/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
```

И что мне делать? )))

p.s. How-to взято отсюда http://blog.fox.geek.nz/2010/09/installing-multiple-perls-with.html

Answer (score 1):

perlbrew install-cpanm ?

Comment: попробовал ((

    sh-3.2$ perlbrew self-upgrade
    Your perlbrew installation appears to be system-wide.Please upgrade through your package manager.

    sh-3.2$ perlbrew install-cpanm
    ERROR: Failed to retrive cpanm executable.

Comment: а так:
perlbrew switch perl-5.10.1
cpan -i App::cpanminus
?

p.s.
может из-за того, что perlbrew из под рута установлен - попробовать снести ~/perl5/perlbrew и заново всё сделать: http://www.perlbrew.pl/ || http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/bin/perlbrew#INSTALLATION

Comment: порыл исходники perlbrew.. увидел, что он пытается с https закачать cpanm.. сделал export https_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy:port - ПОСТАВИЛСЯ)))

Comment: cpanm - встал и работает..
а вот все остальное ((

    sh-3.2$ cpanm LWP
    perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
    sh-3.2$ cpanm Term::ReadKey
    perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
    sh-3.2$ cpanm Net::SSLeay
    perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr

Comment: какого он вообще суется в /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/...

Comment: ..наводит на мысль, что perlbrew как то странно установлен